# Something wrong with $headers

Tags: php

I created a feedback form and have something wrong with $headers, because it works perfect when I give fixed urls to $headers but when i give him variables it stops work. This is my code

```
<?php
$to = "mail@mail.com";
$name =$_POST['name'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$subject =$_POST['subject'];
$messege =$_POST['messege'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $email . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$messege,$headers); 


?>
```

Who can say why?

Answer (score 0):

Share you HTML (form) codes with us to more guidance.

And you can check form method, according to your php codes, form method must be post. and you can echo $_POST['name'] (for example) that you know this filled or empty.

Comment: I checked everythig. That's why I didn't write my form code here. Only that I have written wrong is this $headers .= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $email . "\r\n"; and I don't know how it write correct

Comment: Are you get any email in your address? $email field is filled?

Comment: I printeed the $email and it returned value

Comment: now your problem is you can't get any email via your php code or what?

Comment: No. I can get everything. But mail() doesn't send messege to email. And I don't know why.

Comment: ok, you must read error.log file and can failing reason in this. i recommend run your code and read latest lines.

Comment: Where you run this code? localhost or shared host or ...?

Comment: I got host from reg.ru

Comment: You can ask from reg.ru support team for find error.log (or err.log) file and can find your solution and know what happened in your php code via this log file